# How can I modify the type(ld+json) value with javascript in html label?

Tags: javascript, ejs, hexo

I'm using javascript to modify the "application/ld+json" in html script label, but I cannot select the json value and change it with raw js.

hexo 3.9
os: Linux 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft linux x64
node: 13.0.1

```js
<script id="myjsonid" type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "BlogPosting",
        "mainEntityOfPage": "<%- config.url + url_for(path) %>",
        "headline": "<%- page.title %>",
        "datePublished": "<%= page.date %>",
        "dateModified": "<%= page.updated %>",
        "image": "<%= page.thumbnail %>",
        "author": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "<%= config.author %>",
            "image": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "url": "<%= theme.img.avatar %>"
            },
            "description": "<%- theme.uiux.slogan %>"
        },
        "publisher": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "<%= config.title %>",
            "logo": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "url": "<%= theme.head.high_res_favicon %>"
            }
        },
        "keywords": "<% if(page.tags && page.tags.each) { page.tags.each(function(tag) { %><%- tag.name + ',' %><% })} %><%= theme.head.keywords %>",
        "description": "<% if(page.description) { %><%= page.description %><% } else if(page.excerpt){ %><%= strip_html(page.excerpt).replace(/^s*/, '').replace(/s*$/, '') %><% } else if (config.description){ %><%= config.description %><% } %>"
    }
</script>
<script>
    roundsum = Math.round(Math.random()*"<%= theme.thumbnail.random_amount %>"+1);
    testvar = document.getElementById("myjsonid");
</script>
```

now I don't know what to do, do i miss some api documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`firstChild` is giving you a Text node with the text of the script. You can use its `nodeValue` property ([spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-nodevalue), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue)) both to get and set the text:

```
const script = document.getElementById("myjsonid");
script.firstChild.nodeValue = '{"foo": 1}'; // Completely replace it
console.log(script.firstChild.nodeValue);
```

Live Example:

```js
const script = document.getElementById("myjsonid");
script.firstChild.nodeValue = '{"foo": 1}'; // Completely replace it
console.log(script.firstChild.nodeValue);
```

```html
<script id="myjsonid" type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "BlogPosting",
        "mainEntityOfPage": "<%- config.url + url_for(path) %>",
        "headline": "<%- page.title %>",
        "datePublished": "<%= page.date %>",
        "dateModified": "<%= page.updated %>",
        "image": "<%= page.thumbnail %>",
        "author": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "<%= config.author %>",
            "image": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "url": "<%= theme.img.avatar %>"
            },
            "description": "<%- theme.uiux.slogan %>"
        },
        "publisher": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "<%= config.title %>",
            "logo": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "url": "<%= theme.head.high_res_favicon %>"
            }
        },
        "keywords": "<% if(page.tags && page.tags.each) { page.tags.each(function(tag) { %><%- tag.name + ',' %><% })} %><%= theme.head.keywords %>",
        "description": "<% if(page.description) { %><%= page.description %><% } else if(page.excerpt){ %><%= strip_html(page.excerpt).replace(/^s*/, '').replace(/s*$/, '') %><% } else if (config.description){ %><%= config.description %><% } %>"
    }
</script>
```

You could also use `textContent` ([spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-textcontent), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)) or `innerText` ([spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)) on the `script` element itself:

```
const script = document.getElementById("myjsonid");
script.firstChild.nodeValue = '{}'; // Completely replace it
console.log(script.firstChild.nodeValue);
```

Live Example:

```js
const script = document.getElementById("myjsonid");
script.textContent = '{"foo": 1}'; // Completely replace it
console.log(script.firstChild.nodeValue);
script.innerText = '{"foo": 2}'; // Completely replace it
console.log(script.firstChild.nodeValue);
```

```html
<script id="myjsonid" type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "BlogPosting",
        "mainEntityOfPage": "<%- config.url + url_for(path) %>",
        "headline": "<%- page.title %>",
        "datePublished": "<%= page.date %>",
        "dateModified": "<%= page.updated %>",
        "image": "<%= page.thumbnail %>",
        "author": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "<%= config.author %>",
            "image": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "url": "<%= theme.img.avatar %>"
            },
            "description": "<%- theme.uiux.slogan %>"
        },
        "publisher": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "<%= config.title %>",
            "logo": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "url": "<%= theme.head.high_res_favicon %>"
            }
        },
        "keywords": "<% if(page.tags && page.tags.each) { page.tags.each(function(tag) { %><%- tag.name + ',' %><% })} %><%= theme.head.keywords %>",
        "description": "<% if(page.description) { %><%= page.description %><% } else if(page.excerpt){ %><%= strip_html(page.excerpt).replace(/^s*/, '').replace(/s*$/, '') %><% } else if (config.description){ %><%= config.description %><% } %>"
    }
</script>
```

---

In a comment you've said you want to change one specific part of the structure. To do that, use `JSON.parse` on the string to get an object tree for the JSON, make your change in that tree, and then use `JSON.stringify` to get a JSON string to write back to the `script` element:

```
const script = document.getElementById("myjsonid");
const obj = JSON.parse(script.firstChild.nodeValue);
obj.image = "***THIS IS THE UPDATE***";
script.firstChild.nodeValue = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(script.firstChild.nodeValue);
```

Live Example:

```js
const script = document.getElementById("myjsonid");
const obj = JSON.parse(script.firstChild.nodeValue);
obj.image = "***THIS IS THE UPDATE***";
script.firstChild.nodeValue = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(script.firstChild.nodeValue);
```

```html
<script id="myjsonid" type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "BlogPosting",
        "mainEntityOfPage": "<%- config.url + url_for(path) %>",
        "headline": "<%- page.title %>",
        "datePublished": "<%= page.date %>",
        "dateModified": "<%= page.updated %>",
        "image": "<%= page.thumbnail %>",
        "author": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "<%= config.author %>",
            "image": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "url": "<%= theme.img.avatar %>"
            },
            "description": "<%- theme.uiux.slogan %>"
        },
        "publisher": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "<%= config.title %>",
            "logo": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "url": "<%= theme.head.high_res_favicon %>"
            }
        },
        "keywords": "<% if(page.tags && page.tags.each) { page.tags.each(function(tag) { %><%- tag.name + ',' %><% })} %><%= theme.head.keywords %>",
        "description": "<% if(page.description) { %><%= page.description %><% } else if(page.excerpt){ %><%= strip_html(page.excerpt).replace(/^s*/, '').replace(/s*$/, '') %><% } else if (config.description){ %><%= config.description %><% } %>"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ok,you answer the main problem, but i don't want to completely replace it, in this case, the given value by ejs will be replaced which is not my wish, i want to select the only key such as "image" to fill its value if it is not established.

Comment: @iyume - Well, there's nothing in your question about doing that, so it's no great surprise I didn't address it. :-) You can do that like this: Use `JSON.parse` to parse the string you get into an object structure, make your change in that structure, and then use `JSON.stringify` to get the JSON string to put back in the `script` element.

Comment: ooo,that is, let's try